# Do I need a comma here?

Tags: commas

I want to say something like:

> He wants to play basketball, play volleyball, or go for a walk.

The meaning I'm trying to convey is: he wants to do 1 of 3 things - play basketball, play volleyball, go for a walk

Can I shorten that sentence into:

> He wants to play basketball or volleyball or go for a walk.

Or do I need a comma somewhere. Something like:

> He wants to play basketball or volleyball, or go for a walk

Comment: Punctuation is not grammar. It is merely a matter of style. Your sentence _He wants to play basketball or volleyball or go for a walk._ is correct. Many might even consider writing it like _He wants to play basketball, or volleyball, or go for a walk._

Comment: Adding comma before or is only a requirement in sentences that links two independent clauses..

Answer (score 1):

---

**Comma** used to seperate parts of a sentence or items in lists or to create an absence of sound(as a breath mark)!

If all the items are applicable to the verb, you can seperate them with a comma, without using the same verb again and again.

> He wants to ***play** basketball, **play** volleyball, **play** tennis* .

instead you can write;

> He wants to ***play*** *basketball, volleyball, tennis...*

instead of too many **play** here only comma is enough.

---

When you are writing series of events like these and ending it with another verb or another type of event you can do this;

> He wants to ***play*** *basketball, volleyball,...,* + *and / or* + ***go*** *for a walk, sight seeing, skiing...*.

Each item is seperated with a comma except the items after **and/or** cause **play** verb cannot be applied on *"a walk"*. Instead you can seperate items that are applicable to **go** after seperating them with **and/or**.

---

In your context however you are trying to imply that this person would like to do 1 of 3 different things;

> He wants to ***play** basketball, or volleyball, or **go** for a walk*.

Comma allowed us not to use **play** too many times but still you have to use **or** to imply it is a choise between these options.

When there is a choice between things you can also do this;

> He wants to **either** ***play** basketball, volleyball, or **go** for a walk*.

by getting help from adverb **either** you can ease your pain and get rid of multiple **or** usage too.

---

**Bonus:**

What else we can do with it?

You can keep using comma without in need of seperating with "**and / or**"

> He wants to ***play*** *basketball, volleyball,..., **go** for a walk, sight seeing, skiing...*.

commas before **go** here is applicable to the **play** and commas after **go** is applicable to it self.

You can use it as a second of breath or a shush mark.

> He wants to ***play***, many things. (after **play** breath taken)

> He wants to ***play***, even if it's not safe for him to play. (after the first **play** breath taken or a momentarily shush takes place)

---